# Programmatically scroll ng-repeat with overflow:hidden

Tags: css, angularjs, scroll, zurb-foundation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using the following markup (JADE) to build a pagination with AngularJS and [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/pagination.html).

```
ul.pagination
    li.arrow: a &laquo;
    li(ng-repeat="month in months | orderBy:'_id'" ng-class="month._id === shownMonth ? 'current' : ''")
        a(ng-href="#/months/{{month._id}}") {{ month._id | monthid:'short' }}   
    li.arrow#right-arrow: a &raquo;
```

In the CSS, I've set `overflow: hidden`. This gets me this:

[image: pagination]

Perfect so far, but obviously this could get long.

**How can I make this scroll when the user clicks on the little arrow symbols at the end?**

I've tried doing stuff like `$(...).animate({left: '-=20'})` but it simply gets ignored (I'm guessing because of the Foundation css). Any ideas?

## UPDATE

I've got a semi-working solution, but it's ugly.

I have attached an `ng-show` condition to the repeated list items as such:

```
li(ng-repeat="month in months | orderBy:'_id'" ng-class="month._id === shownMonth ? 'current' : ''" ng-show="month._id >= min && month._id <= max")
```

and after loading my data I do

```
$timeout(function() {
    var availableWidth = $('ul.pagination').width() - 2 * $('ul li.arrow').width();
    var itemWidth = $('li:not(.arrow)').width();
    var total = Math.floor(availableWidth / itemWidth);
    $scope.min = $scope.shownMonth - Math.floor(total / 2);
    $scope.max = $scope.shownMonth + Math.floor(total / 2);
});
```

Then I basically just need to adjust `min` and `max` in an `ng-click` handler for the arrow buttons. This works, more or less, but for some reason, `availableWidth` gets calculated to much, much smaller than the space that's actually available for it - it's off by about 600px! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animating the left position makes no sense. What you want to animate is the horizontal scroll position (element.scrollLeft).

Also, consider removing your arrows out of the list of months. They don't make sense semantically in that list, and they'll end up constraining you when you want to scroll just the months but leave the arrows in place.

Edited to add fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R9QcB/5/ I did this with jQuery for quickness, but scrollLeft is a native javascript property.

It's the CSS that's actually important here moreso than the javascript:

```
#pagination {
    text-align: center;
}
    .nav {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    ul {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        max-width: 75%;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
        li {
            display: inline-block;
            list-style: none;
            color: #fff;
            background: #aaa;
            padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
            margin: 0 0.5em;
        }
```

Basically, you need a containing element that you can update the scrollLeft position of. That containing element has an overflow: hidden on it so that its child elements sit in a series inside the container (which is a result of white-space: nowrap).

Comment: I tried that first, but doing `scrollLeft` didn't do anything - it just got ignored. I have the arrows in the `ul` so they become part of the pagination.

Comment: Ya I figured probably the CSS was the key, but CSS is **definitely** not my strong point. Either way, I would like to avoid bypassing the foundation CSS, so I'm trying to integrate what you've posted into what I have. And, again, getting ignored...where does the magic happen in yours? Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: The magic is in understanding the overflow properties of CSS and the scrollTop and scrollLeft properties of javascript. Here's a really basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/9VajK/ The #overflow-frame div is going to have a scrollLeft property that can be polled (to get its position) or updated (to set its position). In jQuery, this method is $.scrollLeft().

Comment: Ha, I got it! I started manually disabling foundation's CSS rules in the Firefox developer tools until it started working. Turns out they applied a `float: left` to the `li`s in the pagination. I don't know enough CSS to understand why that is keeping it from working, but adding `float: none !important;` to my own stylesheet does the trick. Thanks for pointing me down the right track!